# Feeding charts with variables

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart that shows attendance of employees. By this way I have calculated (within the report) the majority of present and absent employees.  How can I feed the chart with variables?

```
**Key expressions**  - Present, Absent
**Values** - 
Present -70%
Absent -30%
```

Comment: [Charts Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/charts/index.html#charts)

Comment: You should see these post: - http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-charts-and-datasets-jaspersoft-studio , http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/815627/create-pie-chart-variables-report

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

Right click on the chart component and select ‘detail’ tab then add series as you want.